# Possible Causes for Blackberry 9800 OS 6.0.0.141 Simulator For Crashing?

Tags: jquery, blackberry, jquery-mobile, cordova, blackberry-simulator

I am working on a blackberry project and ran into some problems with the simulator and I don't know why it is happening nor how to debug this problem.

What I am using

1. phonegap 1.7
2. cordova.1.7.0.js
3. jquery.1.6.4.js , jquery.ui.1.8.18 , jquery.mobile.1.0.1.js

I am using some other jquery plugins as well.

I am getting a few problems

Problem 1

```
   function onDeviceReady()
    {
      // do your thing!
      alert("PhoneGap is working");

    }

    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    });
```

I have this in my index.html (these are html 5 pages) and when the application loads I see this alert box what is expected. However when I go to an new html page that does not have this code I see this alert box again and I can't figure out why.

I am not sure if this just a buggy version or what as if I go and use "7.0+" simulator I do not get this error anymore.

Problem 2

When I load up the application through the simulator in 6.0.0 it will just randomly crash. Sometimes it will just load up my main page and just crash. Sometimes I have to click around for a while and it will crash.

I try to use the Tools-Show Event Log but it records nothing so I am not sure how to even debug this.

Both of these problems go away if I am using  OS 7.0+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have faced the same issue what you are facing right now.

First of all i would suggest not to use this `$(document).ready(function()`

Do something like this

```
function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

function onDeviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);
}

function onPause() {
}

<body onload="onLoad()">
</body>
```

Secondly the issue what you are facing is because of a buggy 9800 simulator. Download it again from the blackberry site and reinstall it. The issue is that the device ready is called always when you change a page. This was a bug in Blackberry 9800 simulator. Although If you try to run this in any BB OS 7 simulator then  it will work perfectly...

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Well. Not sure if downloading the simulator will fix anything. This has been tried on my computer and another co-worker(who first ran into this problem). We both get the same thing. Why would you not sure the jquery document ready?